# perl XML::Simple print issue

Tags: perl

This my xml file :

data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:BoardTestXMLExport numberOfIndictedComponents="6" testerTestStartTime=".00000:00" testTime=".00000:00" repairStationId="vvts03" testStatus="Reviewed Passed" testerTestEndTime=".00000:00" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/BoardTestXMLExport.xsd" numberOfIndictedPins="0" numberOfComponentsTested="113" numberOfJointsTested="0" numberOfDefects="6" repairStatus="Reviewed Passed">
          <ns1:StationXML testerName="huaemsaoi004" stage="V510"/>
          <ns1:TestXML name="d1">
                    <ns1:IndictmentXML algorithm="bep-3a98730h01l-lf" indictmentType="OCV Fail">
                              <ns1:RepairActionXML repairOperator="1066689" repairTime="2017-11-24T11:35:32.000+08:00" repairActionType="-" indictmentType="OCV Fail" comment="-" repairStatus="False Call"/>
                              <ns1:ComponentXML packageId="EP-3A98730H01L-LF" partId="EP-3A98730H01L-LF" designator="d1"/>
                    </ns1:IndictmentXML>
          </ns1:TestXML>
          <ns1:TestXML name="r2">
                    <ns1:IndictmentXML algorithm="rep-as30112h42l-lf" indictmentType="Right off">
                              <ns1:RepairActionXML repairOperator="1066689" repairTime="2017-11-24T11:35:32.000+08:00" repairActionType="-" indictmentType="Right off" comment="-" repairStatus="False Call"/>
                              <ns1:ComponentXML packageId="EP-AS30112H42L-LF" partId="EP-AS30112H42L-LF" designator="r2"/>
                    </ns1:IndictmentXML>
          </ns1:TestXML>
</ns1:BoardTestXMLExport>
```

I used follow code to print the "IndictmentType"and "name", but it fail to print them, code as below:

```
# use module
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use XML::Simple;
 use Data::Dumper;
 # create object
 my $xml = XML::Simple->new;
# read XML file
 my $data = $xml->XMLin("data.xml",KeyAttr=>"ns1");
 print Dumper($data);
 print $data ->{"ns1:TestXML"}->{"ns1:IndictmentXML"}->{"IndictmentType"};
 print $data ->{"ns1:TestXML"}->{"ns1:IndictmentXML"};
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include your code as text. We cannot copy code to try to run it from an image. The users here are professional programmers that volunteer their time for free to help you, and you cannot expect them to waste time retyping your program. Thanks.

Comment: I guess there is a typo somewhere. `print XML::Simple->new->XMLin(\*DATA, KeyAttr => 'ns1')->{"repairStationId"};` with your XML in the `__DATA__` section produces the correct output.

Comment: You are also clearly on Windows, so your Linux style shebang is unneeded, and I find it odd that you run your program from `D:\work\stuff\stuff/test1.pl`. Where is that forward slash `/` coming from? By the way, please always use `use strict` and `use warnings` in your Perl programs and make sure they compile with those. I am pretty sure `strict` will catch your problem.

Comment: You're very good at OCR, @simbabque! ;-)

Comment: @PerlDuck we practiced speed-typing at the pub after London Perl Workshop with a phone app where you needed to retype some weird text. After a few beers, that gives good practice. ;)

Comment: @simbabque I used the "use warnings" and got the error as follow:use of uninitialized value in print , so what should i do, I am new for perl

Comment: Please [edit] your question and _copy in your REAL code_. I retyped half of it and it worked for me, so you must have a typo in there that we don't see. The error means exactly what it says. The value you are trying to print in the last line is undefined. That's probably because of a typo. But without being able to COPY the ACTUAL code I cannot help you spot it. Or you could copy it from my comment above, which works. When I search for the difference between something, besides using a diff tool, I like to copy the other version on a line above mine and indent so they line up. Easy to read.

Comment: Vote to close because the picture of the output indicates that `$data` contains an element `repairStationID`. The picture of the code shows correct syntax of the two print statements. When retyping the code it works for all of us, so the actual code that produces the error MUST be different from the picture of the code shown. Did you photoshop™ the picture of the code? The problem is not reproducable.

Answer (score 3):

Your code works when I try it on my machine. Of course, because you posted a picture of your code rather than posting it as text (I have no idea why people think that is useful - you're just annoying people who you are asking to help you!), I had to re-type your code and it's possible that I "accidentally" fixed whatever typo is causing your problem - I suspect a mis-match in capitalisation of the key you are trying to print.

It would also help to know which version of XML::Simple you are using. It's possible that you are running up against a bug that has been fixed in a more recent version.

It's worth pointing out a few things. Firstly, the documentation for [XML::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple) contains this text:

> **STATUS OF THIS MODULE**
>
> The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are
>   available which provide more straightforward and consistent
>   interfaces. In particular, [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) is highly recommended and
>   [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) is an excellent alternative.
>
> The major problems with this module are the large number of options
>   (some of which have unfortunate defaults) and the arbitrary ways in
>   which these options interact - often producing unexpected results.
>
> Patches with bug fixes and documentation fixes are welcome, but new
>   features are unlikely to be added.

Given the clarity of that statement, I can't understand why anyone would still be using that module for new development.

You should always have `use strict` and `use warnings` in your code. The first of those will force you to declare you variables (with `my`). And your future maintenance programmers will thank you if you avoid the `new Class` syntax and use `Class->new` instead.

Given all of those things (well, except I haven't replaced XML::Simple), your code would look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

my $xml = XML::Simple->new;

my $data = $xml->XMLin('data.xml', KeyAttr => 'ns1');

print Dumper $data;
print $data->{repairStationId};
```

This code works as expected for me (but, then, so did your original code).

Comment: It's not actually 40k yet! But it's close :D

Comment: @simbabque: I know. I noticed that. It definitely passed 40k last week but over the weekend I lost about 50 points for some unexplained reason.

Comment: Maybe some low-rep user who voted for you got deleted. Look at the positive side. You get to celebrate the 40k twice! :)

Comment: Losing that much is usually due to a user getting deleted.

Comment: Double celebration sounds good :)

Comment: Looks like I just broke through 40k again. Thanks for the votes people :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dave

Comment: Thanks a lot, uses your code it work fine now,,and  I will  try to uses XML::LibXML @DaveCross

Comment: @user: As I said, there's no effective difference between my code and your original code. If it's now working, then that's because you fixed a typo while retyping it.

Comment: @DaveCross, I met an new issue for it, could you help to have a check for it? thanks a lot.

Comment: @user: If you have a new problem, then post a new question.

Comment: similar issue, because new issue need 5 days later@DaveCross

Comment: Asking a new question is still the way to go. This one is done with.

Comment: @user: If you contribute usefully to the site - by answering questions to help others, then you will quickly gain the 10 points needed to remove the new user restrictions (which include the bar on posting questions too quickly). If you want to get anything out of the site, you need to put something into it. It's a lot like life :-)